# removing image from folder after path is removed from db table through mysql trigger

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am still working in my recipe book, at this point, I am trying to remove the image for the recipe if this gets removed.

My database has a table for recipes, with columns "id", "name" and "attachment_id". Also a table called attachments with "id" and "path_to_attachment" columns. (I understand the useless point of having this in two tables, I just need to practise moving around databases and interacting with them).

After lots of messing around yesterday, I added a trigger for this attachment_id, so, when a recipe gets removed, the row for its attachment and path is also removed.

The problem? The image reminds in the "images/" folder. I am now trying to remove the image when the recipe and its attachments are removed from the database...

The image is stored on this folder with this, on recipe.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $attachment_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'attachment_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

   $folder="images/";
   $file = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
   $file_to_upload = $folder . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

   if(move_uploaded_file($file, $file_to_upload)) {
       echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";


   if($attachment_id = add_image($file_to_upload)) {
       if(add_recipe($name, $attachment_id)) {
           header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
      } else {
           $error_message = "Could not add recipe";
      } 
   } else {
           $error_message = "Could not add image";
      } 

   } else {
       echo 'Upload failure';
   }   
}
```

Then, on index.php, I get the attachments and recipes, and I have a button next to each recipe for it to be deleted:

```
$recipes = get_recipes()
$attachments = get_attachments();
$attachment_path = find_path_by_id($recipe['attachment_id']);

<a class="toLink" href="delete_recipe.php?id=' . $recipe['id'] . '" title="delete recipe"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this recipe?');">Delete recipe</a>
```

On delete_recipe.php:

```
     $recipeId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$attachment_path ?????
          if(delete_recipe($recipeId) == true) {
              delete_attachment($attachment_path);
              echo $attachment_path; die();
              header('Location: index.php');
             exit;
          } else {
               $error_message = "Could not delete recipe";
          }
```

On fuctions.php:

```
 function get_recipes() { 
       include'db_connection.php';
        try {
        return $conn->query("SELECT * FROM recipes");

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error:' . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
            return array();
        }
        return true;
    }

    function get_attachments() { 
       include'db_connection.php';
        try {
        return $conn->query("SELECT * FROM attachments");

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error:' . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
            return array();
        }
        return true;
    }

    function find_path_by_id($attachment_id = ':attachment_id') {
        include 'db_connection.php'; 

          $sql = 'SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE id=:attachment_id LIMIT 1'; 

         try {
          $results = $conn->prepare($sql);  
         $results->bindParam(':attachment_id', $attachment_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
          $results->execute();
         } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
            return array();
        }
          return $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    }

            function add_image($attachment_path= ':attachment_path') {
                 include 'db_connection.php';
                try {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO attachments(attachment_path) VALUES (:attachment_path)";

                    $results = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $results->bindParam(':attachment_path', $attachment_path, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
                    $results->execute();
                    $id = $conn->lastInsertId();    

                $conn = null;

                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
                    return false;
                }
              return $id;     
            }

            function display_image($attachment_id = ':attachment_id') {
                 include 'db_connection.php'; 

                 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE id=:attachment_id LIMIT 1';

                       try {
                  $results = $conn->prepare($sql);  
                  $results->bindParam(':attachment_id', $attachment_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);    
                  $results->execute();
                 } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
                    return array();
                }
                  return $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            }
```

The problem is, I can't get the attachment_path once I clicked delete recipe. I have tried to add in  but I don't want to send it on the url, and I can't get the path once it is processing the "delete recipe".

My thoughts were,once the recipe gets deleted, I create a function to find the name of the file inside the images directory and then, I delete it, but, as I said, I don't know how can I pass the image name to the delete_recipe.php file.

I guess it must be a more logical way of doing this.... but I don't know how... any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function for delete image from folder `unlink($attachment_path)`, attachment path should be for example  images/abc.jpg

```
// image path return from delete_recipe() function
$attachment_path = delete_recipe($recipeId);
if(isset($attachment_path)) {
  unlink($attachment_path);
  header('Location: index.php');
} else {
   $error_message = "Could not delete recipe";
}
```

Comment: I have tried already. But I got to the same problem, I don't know how to pass the value for $attachment_path at this point...

Comment: I guess you use delete_recipe() function for delete record from the table, before you delete the record you have to get image name for a variable, then delete the record. then set image name as return value.